I have advanced running two versions of the same project at the same time for debugging, but still have issues
I have an older version of a C# Blazor project that runs well, and a newer modified version that has a number of problems.  I want to run them them side by side and step by step for debugging.
With the help of others I have learned to adjust the ports in launchsettings.json so the versions run side by side without clashing.
Adjusting the ports was a big advancement but still not enough. Regardless of which one version starts, once the other starts it breaks with the following message:

Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.
Failed to launch browser: ' Failed to run browser!
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/googlechrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

The linked documentation was not helpful.
Would appreciate pointers on getting debugging value from output window
Thanks.

Perfect. Solved!  For further learning, what is the deep down cause of the problem?

Run one project in Chrome and the other in FireFox or Edge.
The datalink for the debugger, whatever that is, is not shareable.

Good understandable answer. Thanks
